# Define max number of entities in many-to-many

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I want to design a database with a many-to-many relationship with entities students and teams. Each team can have many students and each student can participate in many teams. However each team can have max 10 students. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: *What is the right way to do this?* Create triggers (BEFORE INSERT and BEFORE UPDATE) which checks this condition and executes SIGNAL if the condition is not met.

Answer (score 0):

Some things are best done by the application.  The database can deal with the many-to-many, but the app should handle the "10" limit.